# JS скрипт игнорирует условие и срабатывает без него

Tags: javascript, html, html5

У меня есть типичное модальное окно. Я хочу, чтобы модальное окно закрывалось, если пользователь кликнет по зоне вне информационного блока попапа (по затемнённому пространству).

Проблема заключается в том, что скрипт срабатывает по клику не только в затемнённой области, а в принципе в любом месте, в том числе по самому контенту модального окна.

```js
const openPopUp = document.getElementById('open_pop_up');
const closePopUp = document.getElementById('pop_up_close');
const popUp = document.getElementById('pop_up');

openPopUp.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  popUp.classList.add('active');

});

const entryDisplay = document.querySelectorAll('.pop_up');
entryDisplay[0].onclick = function(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  if (event.target = entryDisplay[0]) {
    entryDisplay[0].classList.remove('active');
  };
};
```

```css
.pop_up {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: translate(-90%) scale(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 100;
}

.pop_up.active {
  transform: translateY(0%) scale(1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.pop_up_container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.pop_up_body {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.pop_up_body .nws-item__caption ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.pop_up_body .nws-item__caption span {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.pop_up_body .nws-item__date {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.pop_up_close {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #892bff;
  color: #fff;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
}

.pop_up_close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="pop_up" id="pop_up">
  <div class="pop_up_container">
    <div class="pop_up_body" id="pop_up_body">
      <div class="nws-item__image"><img src="img/news/card1.jpeg" alt="picture"></div>
      <div class="nws-item__date">20 Aug 2022</div>
      <hr>
      <div class="nws-item__title">Заголовок окна</div>
      <div class="nws-item__caption">Описание в информационном модальном окне.</div>
      <div class="pop_up_close" id="pop_up_close">&#10006;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="open_pop_up">Открыть</button>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D++%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5+     .............  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D++%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE

Comment: У вас внутри if стоит присваивание

Answer (score 0):

Решение лежит в том, что все Event передаются так-же всем Child элементам.

https://codepen.io/latdev/pen/JjLbpPr

```js
function inside(target, inside) {
  let result = null,
    node = target;
  while (node !== null) {
    if (node.isEqualNode(inside)) return true;
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  return false;
}

document.addEventListener('click', $event => {
  let debug = document.getElementById('debug');
  let modal = document.getElementById('modal');
  if (!inside($event.target, modal)) {
    debug.textContent = "You clicked Window";
    return;
  }
  debug.textContent = "You clicked Modal";
});
```

```css
#modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 115%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 320px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  height: 180px;
  margin-top: -240px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <input id="modal/test-input">
</div>
<h3 id="debug">Click on modal or outside</h3>
```

Comment: А что делает `result` в функции `inside`?

Comment: Зачем вам codepen?) Вы же явно знаете в отличии от новичков, что тут есть Фрагмент кода, который такие простые вещи, прекрасно запускает :)

Comment: Ему это не надо. Посмотри на разметку в вопросе.

Comment: @EzioMercer, ссылку на codepen можно было и оставить - вдруг кому пригодится.

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st видимо - нечего. Просто после тяжёлого рабочего дня притупилось сознание. +) Если хорошо капнуть, то вообще функция inside вовсе не нужна, в новых браузерах наследие можно вообще 1й строчкой решить, просто не помню точно как, а гуглить лень.

Comment: Загуглил....  `Node.contains(element)` где `Node` это parent, а `element` это target.

`let ClickOnModal = modal.isEqualNode($event.target)) || modal.contains($event.target);`

Comment: @EugeneX, да насчёт `contains` в курсе был. Мне просто функция понравилась) Так что всё пончл, спасибо!

Comment: @Qwertiy  Кому понадобится?) Это же простая разметка... Ну не знаю, я всегда убираю ссылки, если полностью всё можно запускать в Фрагмент кода

Comment: @EzioMercer, ну может кто-то форкнуть захочет и поэкспериментировать - там это проще, чем тут.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю можно попробовать добавить доп. условие когда попап открыт и остановить событие клика

```
if (popUp.classList.contains('active'){
e.stopPropagation();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно помнить, что событие от целевого элемента будет передаваться вверх по иерархии, вплоть до `window`, а не наоборот.

Если событие дошло до window, при этом "по пути" отсутствует `.pop_up_body` или целевым элементом является кнопка закрытия, то закрываем модальное окно.
Мы можем повесить обработчик на `.pop_up_body`, а можем использовать метод [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) для поиска ближайшего родителя:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.closest('.pop_up_body') || closePopUp === e.target) {
    popUp.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

Также в обработчике кнопки открытия нужно добавить `stopPropagation()`, чтобы событие не дошло до window и окно сразу не закрылось:

```js
openPopUp.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  popUp.classList.add('active');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Вот и все премудрости...

Пример целиком:

```js
const openPopUp  = document.getElementById('open_pop_up');
const closePopUp = document.getElementById('pop_up_close');
const popUp      = document.getElementById('pop_up');

openPopUp.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  popUp.classList.add('active');
  e.stopPropagation();
});

window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.closest('.pop_up_body') || closePopUp === e.target) {
    popUp.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.pop_up {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: translate(-90%) scale(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 100;
}

.pop_up.active {
  transform: translateY(0%) scale(1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.pop_up_container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.pop_up_body {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.pop_up_body .nws-item__caption ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.pop_up_body .nws-item__caption span {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.pop_up_body .nws-item__date {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.pop_up_close {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #892bff;
  color: #fff;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
}

.pop_up_close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="pop_up" id="pop_up">
  <div class="pop_up_container">
    <div class="pop_up_body" id="pop_up_body">
      <div class="nws-item__image"><img src="img/news/card1.jpeg" alt="picture"></div>
      <div class="nws-item__date">20 Aug 2022</div>
      <hr>
      <div class="nws-item__title">Заголовок окна</div>
      <div class="nws-item__caption">Описание в информационном модальном окне.</div>
      <div class="pop_up_close" id="pop_up_close">&#10006;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="open_pop_up">Открыть</button>
```